# Does a strictly increasing function satisfying this exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, contest-math, natural-numbers

Is there a function $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ (strictly increasing) , such that the following is always true:

$$f(f(f(n))) = n + 2f(n)?$$

This is a homework problem from a contest math course I desperately need help with. I tried, but haven't made any significant progress.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just sketch:** first of all, I'd focus on linear estimations $f(n)\approx g(x)$, where: $$g(x) = \alpha x,\qquad \alpha\ge 1,$$ from where $$\alpha^3 = 1+2\alpha,$$ therefore $$\alpha_1=-1, \\ \alpha_2=1 - \varphi, \\ \alpha_3 = \varphi,$$ where $\varphi=...$ (?)

Since $f$ is increasing function, we choose $\alpha=\varphi>1$.

Since $f$ is $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, $-$ there is reason to focus on functions like $$f(n)=round(\varphi n),$$ or something based on Fibonacci sequence: 
$$
f(\color{blue}{1})=\color{red}{2};\\ 
f(\color{blue}{2})=\color{red}{3};\\
f(\color{blue}{3})=\color{red}{5};\\
f(4)=6;\\
f(\color{blue}{5})=\color{red}{8};\\
f(6)=10;\\
f(7)=11;\\
f(\color{blue}{8})=\color{red}{13};\\
f(9)=15;\\
f(10)=16;\\
f(11)=18;\\
\ldots
$$

Check first values: 

$fff(1)=ff(2)=f(3)=5=1+2f(1)$;

$fff(2)=ff(3)=f(5)=8=2+2f(2)$;

$fff(3)=ff(5)=f(8)=13=3+2f(3);$

$fff(4)=ff(6)=f(10)=16=4+2f(4);$

$fff(5)=ff(8)=f(13)=21=5+2f(5).$

I'm not sure whether it will work further;) but you can try to derive/construct/prove something from here.

Comment: I agree with your approach. If $(a_k)_{k\geq 1}$ is a sequence of positive integers so that $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_n$ and $a_2 > a_1$. Then no two $a_k$'s have the same value, and so, we may set the values of $f$ on $\{a_k:k\geq1\}$ by $f(a_k)=a_{k+1}$. Now this satisfies $$f(f(f(a_k)))=a_{k+3}=a_k+2a_{k+1}=a_k+2f(a_k).$$ I guess that your choice eventually falls into this type of construction.